# How to handle with empty dataframes in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I noticed that sometimes I get errors in my R scripts when I forget checking whether the dataframe I'm working on is actually empty (has zero rows).

For example, when I used apply like this

`apply(X=DF,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(row) !any(vec[ row[["start"]]:row[["end"]] ]))`

and `DF` happened to be empty, I got an error about the subscripts.

Why is that? Aren't empty dataframes valid? Why does `apply()` with `MARGIN=1` even try to do anything when there are no rows in the dataframe? Do I really need to add a condition before each such apply to make sure the dataframe isn't empty?

Thank you!

Comment: Aren't you confusing standard *pplys with `plyr` ones?

Comment: What you want as a result in case of an empty `data.frame`? A list? `NULL`? `NA`? `FALSE`? Maybe you could eliminate empty `data.frame`'s earlier in your code?

Comment: @mbq I'm not sure. When I use `apply()` with `MARGIN=1`, how exactly does it work? I thought it sends each row to `FUN` and aggregate the results.

Comment: Sorry, this comment was stupid. Ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a side note: apply always accesses the function you use at least once. If the input is a dataframe without any rows but with defined variables, it sends "FALSE" as an argument to the function. If the dataframe is completely empty, it sends a logical(0) to the function.

```
> x <- data.frame(a=numeric(0))
> str(x)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: num 

> y <- apply(x,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){print(x)})
[1] FALSE

> x <- data.frame()

> str(x)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables

> y <- apply(x,MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){print(x)})
logical(0)
```

So as Joshua already told you, either control before the apply whether the dataframe has rows, or add a condition in the function within the apply.

EDIT : 
This means you should take into account that length(x)==0 is not a very good check, you need to check whether either length(x==0) or !x is TRUE if both possibilities could arise :
(Code taken from Joshua)

```
apply(X=data.frame(),MARGIN=1,  # empty data.frame
  FUN=function(row) {
    if(length(row)==0 || !row) {return()}
    !any(vec[ row[["start"]]:row[["end"]] ])
  })
```

Comment: I think it might be better to use `if(length(row)==0 || !row)` (`||` instead of `|`), otherwise we might get warnings saying `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Comment: p.s. where is this behavior of `apply` that you have mentioned documented?

Comment: @David : in the code above. Sometimes testing it out yourself gives you already a lot of insight. I remembered I tried it out a while ago.

Comment: "Apply always accesses the function you use at least once" - thanks for pointing that out. Is that documented somewhere? The behavior really threw me for a loop despite having read the docs for the function. How would I have known it does that if not for this answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Yetanotherjosh I didn't find this exact statement in the help files, but derived if from how the function is supposed to work and testing it out. I learnt a lot of things about R by trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

This has absolutely nothing to do with `apply`.  The function you are applying does not work when the data.frame is empty.

```
> myFUN <- function(row) !any(vec[ row[["start"]]:row[["end"]] ])
> myFUN(DF[1,])  # non-empty data.frame
[1] FALSE
> myFUN(data.frame()[1,])  # empty data.frame
Error in row[["start"]]:row[["end"]] : argument of length 0
```

Add a condition to your function.

```
> apply(X=data.frame(),MARGIN=1,  # empty data.frame
+  FUN=function(row) {
+    if(length(row)==0) return()
+    !any(vec[ row[["start"]]:row[["end"]] ])
+  })
NULL
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how `apply(MARGIN=1)` works. I assumed it send each row to `FUN` and aggregates the results. If that was the case, an empty data frame shouldn't have failed since `FUN` would never have been called. So I guess this isn't the case. I looked at the documentation but still didn't figure out how it works exactly.

Comment: `apply` does not aggregate.  It puts the results of the calls to `FUN` on portions ("margins") of `X` into an object.  The resulting object is defined in the first paragraph in the "Value" section of `?apply`.  I'm not sure why you assumed `FUN` wouldn't be called if `X` is empty; the documentation doesn't even hint at that behavior.

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but what happens when the data frame is not empty but contain values.  I believe if you put a data frame with multiple rows into this function it will spit out an error

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's related to 0-row data.frame:

```
X <- data.frame(a=numeric(0))
str(X)
# 'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ a: num 
apply(X,1,sum)
# integer(0)
```

Try use `traceback()` after error to see what exactly cause it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use mapply instead:

```
kk <- data.frame( start = integer(0), end = integer(0) )
kkk <- data.frame( start = 1, end = 3 )

vect <- rnorm( 100 ) > 0

with(kk,  mapply( function(x, y) !any( vect[x]:vect[y] ), start, end ) )
with(kkk, mapply( function(x, y) !any( vect[x]:vect[y] ), start, end ) )
```